# Find if a list in text file of 20 apps are installed in a windows 10 desktop with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Find if a list of apps in text file of apps are installed in a windows 10 desktop with powershell. I am using below script.

```
$installedapps = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name

$applist = Get-content -path "C:\Temp\desiredapps.txt"

foreach ($app in $applist)
{

    if ($installedapps -contains $app)
    {
        write-host $app is installed
    }

    else
    { 
        write-host $app is not installed
    }

}
```

to test the script I have created desiredapps.txt by

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name >> C:\Temp\desiredapps.txt
```

before running the script.
But unfortunately, the output says apps are not installed. Please suggest.

Comment: Change `$installedapps = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name` to `$installedapps = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product).Name`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked!!.
just curious what was the issue?

Comment: The first one would return you the whole property, but you need only the value. The second one does that. However you could use -ExpandProperty instead of -Property switch in Select-Object.

Comment: Win32_Product does not provide information on all of the software installed on your PC, it only represents those installed using Windows Installer, _(generally, `.msi` files)_. If software uses any other installation package, then you're out of luck using Win32_Product.